# split each element in another elements in python list, fast way

Tags: python, list, split

I wish to split some representative 64-bits elements of a python list into another python list composed by individual hexadecimals.

Input:

```
['4d5a900003000000', '04000000ffff0000', ...]
```

Desired output:

```
['4', 'd', '5', ..., '0', '4', '0', ...]
```

Comment: You have told us what you want to accomplish. But what have you tried, and just where are you stuck? And what do you want us to tell you?

Comment: If you know that a `str` is a sequence, then this question is identical: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
s = ['4d5a900003000000', '04000000ffff0000']
new_s = [i for b in s for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['4', 'd', '5', 'a', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Comment: Do you really want to answer a "question" that does not actually state a question and shows no work from the questioner?